# xPage timeout and new login

Tags: xpages

I have these problems after timeout happens and when I click somwhere on xPage component:

1. it shows login page in some frame (not as a separate full login page), e.g. if I click somewhere in a view or data table - it still shows the xPage but login window appears in the data table frame
2. seems all CSS formatting fail after repeated login.

how to fix each problem? Assume it should somehow reload the page that doesn't happen after timeout/login.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the Keep Alive component from the Extension library. Or using this xSnippet
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=keeping-your-xpage-session-alive-%E2%80%93-without-keepsessionalive

If you want the timeout to happen use this code in the onload event

```
setInterval(function(){
XSP.partialRefreshGet("#{id:hiddenxpdiv}", {
   onError: function() {
window.location.href=window.location.href;
}}
}, 300000);
```

Comment: but I do want timeout happen

Comment: Do a partial refresh get and if you get an error do a full refresh. Then the login page should show up in full screen

Comment: where should I do partial refresh? The problem happens if I click anywhere on the form (button, field, view, view column sort, etc..)

Comment: Add a an xp:div somewhere on you form name it hiddenxpdiv
Add style visibility:hidden
Add a computed text inside it with @Now() as the value of it

Answer (score 0):

You could hijack all partial refreshs on your XPage using the little snippet in the answer of this question: [XPages: Get the contents of a - this._partialRefresh AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776503/xpages-get-the-contents-of-a-this-partialrefresh-ajax-call)

In the "hijacked" function, you could check for a specific header returned by the server to identify if you are still logged on or not. If not, you can do a redirect or reload the whole page.

To add the header, you can code it in the beforeRenderResponse event of your XPage, or use a phase listener. The phase listener could look like this:

```
package ch.hasselba.xpages.util;

import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class IAmAlivePhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) ec.getResponse();
        response.addHeader("X-I_AM_ALIVE", "1");
    }

    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {}

}
```

To activate the phase listener, you have to add it to the *faces-config.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
  <lifecycle>
    <phase-listener>ch.hasselba.xpages.util.IAmAlivePhaseListener</phase-listener>
  </lifecycle>
</faces-config>
```

Now, the HTTP Header *X-I_AM_ALIVE* is added to any valid XPages request.

The code to check for the HTTP header looks like this:

```
if( !dojo._xhr )
  dojo._xhr = dojo.xhr; 

var loadOld;

function hijacked( response, ioArgs ){
  var isAlive = ioArgs.xhr &&
  ioArgs.xhr.getResponseHeader("X-I_AM_ALIVE");

  if( !isAlive ){
      window.location.href = window.location.href;
      return false;
  }

  loadOld( response, ioArgs ); // call the original function 
}

dojo.xhr = function( mode, args, bool ){
  loadOld = args["load"];
  args["load"] = hijacked;
  dojo._xhr( mode, args, bool );
}
```

As soon the header is not available, the partial refresh / event execution is stopped and the whole site is reloaded. The HTTP Header is not added when the login form appears.

**EDIT:**

When doing a partial refresh, the client sends a request to the server and expects HTML in the response to overwrite / replace the existing elements in the DOM tree. The replaced DOM elemement is defined by the refresh id.

The request to the server is sent as a xhr request, which checks the return code first before the DOM is replaced. If an error occurs (f.e. HTTP return code 404), then the *onError* method of the Partial refresh is called, otherwise (HTTP return code 200) the *onComplete*.

The problem with timeouts and XPages is that the HTTP response code of the login screen always 200 (OK). When a session is timed out and the client makes xhr request to the server, he receives a "good response" from the server and replaces the existing DOM with the returned HTML code. But in this case, it is the HTML from the login screen.
After replacing the refreshed DOM element with it, the markup of the existing DOM is destroyed, and eventually the XPage is not working anymore (because of JavaScript errors).

While you can not add a HTTP header to the login screen or change the response code, my idea was to do it the other way round: Instead of adding a header to the login screen and identify a "bad response", my solution adds a header to identify the "good" responses.

In my eyes this is the easiest solution which should work on any application without change the existing code (just add a few lines and add the CSJS into a theme).

Comment: is there any graceful solution? I found that rendering problem happens to the pages where OneUI theme enabled and Extension Library Application Layout is used